# How about using Cucumber on desktop software testing

Tags: testing, cucumber

Cucumber is a very powerful BDD tool in rails web application development.
But, my question would be, can we use cucumber in desktop software testing area?
I really like the BDD conception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest getting the book, Scripted GUI Testing With Ruby, by http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/idgtr

Basically you need some way to drive your OS 
On Windows you can use win32ole to drive Wscript e.g.

```
s = WIN32OLE.new 'Wscript.Shell'
s.Exec 'notepad'
```

You don't mention what OS etc...

Comment: Hi macarthy thank you very much for the hint! Yes, my target OS would be Windows. I will first read the Scripted GUI Testing with Ruby. Thanks again.